# Stack of curves and universal deformations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-stacks

I've just started studying algebraic stacks and I have a very basic question.

I've learned the notion of Deligne Mumford stack and I've seen as the stack of stable curves $\overline{\mathcal{M}_g}$ is one.

What I would like to understand is why "locally $\overline{\mathcal{M}_g}$ can be seen as the universal deformation of a stable curve". Can you suggest a good reference for that?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't this just the definition of the moduli stack? Look at the Deligne-Mumford paper, it contains everything you want (and more).

Comment: Over an etale cover by a scheme (the existence of which is the content of it being a DM stack), the pullback of the "universal curve" over the complete local ring at any point is the (algebraization of) the universal deformation of the fiber curve based at that point.

Comment: Deformation theory from the point of view of fibered categories Mattia Talpo, Angelo Vistoli http://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0497